# Column name not being passed as struct key after arrays_zip

Tags: pyspark, struct

Code:

```
test = df.select("struct.ids",F.arrays_zip("struct.score","cand_ids").alias("cand_ids_score_map"))
```

df schema:

```
root
 |-- cand_ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- struct: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- ids: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- score: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
```

test output Schema:

```
root
 |-- ids: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cand_ids_score_map: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- 0: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cand_ids: long (nullable = true)
```

I would have expected this:

```
root
 |-- ids: long (nullable = true)
 |-- cand_ids_score_map: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- score: float (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- cand_ids: long (nullable = true)
```

This seems simple, but googling hasn't helped.

Example:

df :

```
cand_ids   struct
[1,2,3]    [[1, [1.0,0.1,0.3]],[2, [0.1,1.0,0.4]], [3, [0.3,0.4,1.0]]
```

test:

```
ids  cand_ids_score_map
1.   [[1.0, 1], [0.1, 2], [0.3,3]]
2.   [[0.1, 1], [1.0, 2], [0.4,3]]
3.   [[0.3, 1], [0.4, 2], [1.0,3]]
```

Comment: Can you share sample input data and expected output?

Comment: Ah, good call. Added

Comment: Your `struct` column looks like `array<struct>`, not just `struct`?